# What’s the Fermi energy of a Dirac fermion?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, dirac-equation, fermi-energy

Knowing that the energy of a Dirac fermion is $$
\varepsilon(\vec{k})= \pm \sqrt{\left(m c^2\right)^2+(\hbar c k)^2},
$$
Why is the chemical potential $0$ at $T=0$? Since the density of state is $0$ between $-mc^2 < E < mc^2$, why can’t it be any value in this interval?

Any demonstration or explanation is appreciated.